# How can I interpret this use of Python's super statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, super

I've been reading through some code and came across something that makes me think I understand `super` less well than I thought I did. What I saw was:

```
class Model(object):
    '''Abstract base model class.
    '''

    ...

    def get_config(self, verbose=0):
         '''Return the configuration of the model
            as a dictionary.

            To load a model from its configuration, use
            `keras.models.model_from_config(config, custom_objects={})`.
         '''
         config = super(Model, self).get_config()
```

Now, the `Model` class only inherits from `object`, so why is there a `super`? Does the `object` class have a `get_config` method ? (Not that I can see). Is this some sort of defensive programming technique, in case a class comes between `object` and `Model`? If so, how often & why does that sort of thing happen? If not, is there some other reason for this `super`?

Comment: Check out [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) - basically, `super` does not mean "superclass". It means "next in the MRO".  _If so, how often & why does that sort of thing happen?_ Always when multiple inheritance is in play.

Comment: @Rogalski - OK, but the way Model has been defined, isn't object next in the mro? If so, why look for a method that doesn't seem to be there?

Comment: Yes, it is, but as comment says, it's an _abstract base model class._. Concrete implementations would most likely use multiple inheritance to inject correct `get_config()` method. Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with `keras` source.

Comment: @Rogalski - Thanks, you're absolutely right. There is multiple inheritance involved and the super was used to help move through classes in the __mro__.

Answer (score 1):

`object` does not have a valid instance method `get_config()` so this code, specifically, should not work. However, super essentially takes the parent class of a derived class. This is Python2 syntax. In Python3, you can simply call `super()` with no parameters.

Anyways, here's an example:

```
class Number(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        equal = super(Number, self).__eq__(other)
        print("{} and {} are {}equal".format(self, other, "not " if not equal else ""))
        return equal

    def __str__(self):
        return "Number({})".format(super(Number, self).__str__())

i = Number(5)
j = Number(7)
print(i == j) # Output:
"""
Number(5) and Number(7) are not equal
False
"""
```

This inherits from `int` and will modify the instance methods of int, while still being able to use the original methods.

In order for this code to work, you could overload the `object` class (I do not recommend this...).

```
class object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_config(self):
        print("Getting object Config")
        return "config"


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = None

    def get_config(self):
        self.config = super(Foo, self).get_config()
        print("Getting Foo Config")

i = Foo()
i.get_config()
print(i.config)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code does work (it's a snippet of Keras code). The trick is (as @Rogalski explained) that Model is an `abstract` class, so the super is used to help go to the next method as determined by the `mro`. This seems (I think) to depend on classes that inherit from the Model class having multiple inheritancee